# php loading problems

Tags: php

I am using php and mysql to grab and display details depending on the user request. The problem that I am having is while the results are loading none of the other files are accessible to anyone.
For an example when someone is using results.php none of the other users are able to access listall.php until the results.php is loaded completely.

Can someone please tell me how to make possible that any user can access any part of the site.

Comment: Sounds hard to believe: There should not be per-file locking for PHP scripts served through a web server. Can you tell some more details about your setup? Maybe there is something inside the script causing a lock?

Comment: Agreeing with Pekka, upload your .htaccess file also

Comment: im running through my localhost using WAMP.

Comment: paste some code because this is hard to believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you're using shared sessions, or a broken custom session handler, and the second request is blocking waiting for the first request to `session_commit()`.